# Не отправляется сообщение в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу сделать так, что-бы при /start бот писал два сообщения. Не отправляется. Отправляется только одно.

вот код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_mes(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет") #Это сообщение не отправляется

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_mes():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")
    elif message.text.lower() == "пока":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "покааа")
    elif message.text.lower() == "два сообщения":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Первое сообщение")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Второе сообщение")
    elif message.text.lower() == "стикер":
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgIAAxkBAAKuLF68vbJASe0jqQ_pf9AH1i88F-6UAAIwAAMtPOUf66yXalMGWnIZBA")
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgUAAxkBAAKuIl68vU54z5CKn8yiI5aMbejbE6fhAAJ4HQACxlHGFdwoS47_pMgbGQQ")
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgIAAxkBAAKuVl68v_nXqzk3VGZBVyvSwfLM_D3jAAIwAAMFCzQP4lYNyXYr3ZoZBA")
    elif message.text.lower() == "изображение":
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open("coding.png", "rb"))

bot.polling()
```

Comment: проверил ваш код - оба сообщения отправляются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверил, всё работает! 
Но!
Вот эта часть кода дублируется, ее есть смысл убрать

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
    def start_mes():
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")
```

Плюс, тут у Вас ошибка: def start_mes(): не хватает слова  message

Плюс, вот тут в условии написано слово Привет с большой буквы, при этом Вы указываете в коде, что принимать символы с маленькой буквы

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
   if message.text.lower == "Привет":
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")
```